# Lock Screen not respecting nowPlayingInfo dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm trying to get my podcast app to display content in the lock screen, as well as respect the play/pause controls. Here is my code:

```
- (void)playEpisodeAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    _currentIndex = index;
    TalkPodEpisode *episode = self.playlist[index];
    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:episode.url];
    [self.player play];
    _playing = YES;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    NSDictionary *lockScreenInfo = @{MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:self.currentEpisode.title,
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: @"The Talk Pod",
                                 MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.player.rate],
                                          MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self currentPlaybackTime]]};
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = lockScreenInfo;


}
```

Weirdly enough, here's what happens:

1. responding and handling events works just fine
2. the artist and title show up on the lock screen
3. the progress slider shows --:--, and no playback progress is shown
4. the duration of the episode doesn't appear either.

Here is the code to get the current elapsed time:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)currentPlaybackTime {

    CMTime time = self.player.currentTime;
    if (CMTIME_IS_VALID(time)) {

        return time.value/time.timescale;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the code for toggling play & pause:

```
- (void)playPause {

    if (self.player) {

        if (_playing) {

            [self.player pause];
            _playing = NO;

        } else {

            [self.player play];
            _playing = YES;

        }

        NSMutableDictionary *lockScreenInfo = [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo mutableCopy];
        lockScreenInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.player.rate];
        lockScreenInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self currentPlaybackTime]];
        [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = lockScreenInfo;

    }

}
```

Anyone know how to fix this? what's confusing me is that *Some* of the stuff shows up on the screen, but the current playback information doesn't. Again, receiving and handling events works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set Playback Duration key in nowPlayingInfo dictionary.
Look at my post for another question, it works fine in my app.
[Stack : Show seek track duration on control center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603591/1101477)