# Remote command seek forward (or backward) does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, avfoundation, remote-control

I want to be able to seek forward and backward from the lock screen. The code is pretty simple:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[commandCenter.seekForwardCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
    /// seek forward
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.seekBackwardCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
    /// seek backward
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];
```

However on the lock screen the playback progress view is not seek-able.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041075/how-to-show-seek-track-duration-on-control-center) is a similar issue, but I need to use `MPRemoteCommandCenter` (to disable some of default controls). May be somebody can help us both)

Comment: were you able to achieve it then?