# iOS: It there a way to get and set the current playback position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback

The idea isn't so much providing information to the user in the lock screen (see [How to set current playback duration and elapsed time on iOS 7 lockscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800889/how-to-set-current-playback-duration-and-elapsed-time-on-ios-7-lockscreen) for that) but rather I want my app to read the playback position in seconds, then if that value is above a certain threshold skip back by that threshold.  If it's less than that threshold and the current track is in a playlist queue, determine the length of the previous track in the queue, and go back to that track, setting playback position to:

```
position = last.length - threshold + last_position
```

Where last is the previous track and last_position is the playback position in the track which was playing when the event occurred.

I'm using the Model / ControllerView spec for my app so I have my UIEvents trapped in the Controller.  I just can't quite grasp how I get the current playback position.  How would I capture a reference to the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter?  I'm writing in Objective-C.