# now playing info not showing on lock screen

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am switching my music playing app from `AVPlayer` to `MPMusicPlayerController`. When the App uses `AVPlayer`, the now playing info shows as expected. But if I use `MPMusicPlayerController`, I see the now playing controls in the command centre, but not on the lock screen. Is there some additional step required when using `MPMusicPlayerController`?

The only work around I have been able to think of is to run an `AVPlayer` simultaneously with a silent track - but this is a horrible hack to contemplate.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800889/how-to-set-current-playback-duration-and-elapsed-time-on-ios-7-lockscreen

Comment: Thanks for the link, perhaps the comment in one of the answers is a clue....

Comment: I have this same problem, but with applicationQueuePlayer. Command centre has the info and allows control, but nothing shows on the lock screen at all. I'm fairly certain it was working at one point earlier, so wondered if it was an iOS version update difference?

Comment: Thanks for that comment. It does show up with the system player, but it should show up for both. If you had it show before, it is sounding like a bug to me.

Comment: I opened an Apple DTS ticket (and filed a bug report) about this, I am informed that the now playing info should show up when using [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]. So it looks like an Apple bug to me.

Comment: Hi there, did you by any chance get confirmation that this is a bug? I'm struggling with this as well

Comment: Yes - confirmed that it is a bug. Please file a bug report if you can - for me this is almost a show stopper, since it affects car play too.