# MPRemoteCommandCenter disabled all controls

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

Hello dear colleagues i need your help. When i add MPChangePlaybackPositionCommand all my controls (Play/Pause/Rew/Next track on lockscreen) has been disabled automatically. Slider of Playback on lockscreen works perfectly but i can not push no one controls button for why - i don't know.

Also i tried this:

```
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand setEnabled:YES];
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
```

My code is very easy:

```
 MPChangePlaybackPositionCommand *changePlaybackPositionCommand = [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter] changePlaybackPositionCommand];
    [changePlaybackPositionCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(onChangePlaybackPositionCommand:)];

- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus) onChangePlaybackPositionCommand:
(MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent *) event

{
    [[[PlayerPlistController utilise]miniplayer] seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(event.positionTime, 1)];

    NSLog(@"changePlaybackPosition to %f", event.positionTime);

    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}

NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[songInfo setObject:NAME_TITLE forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
[songInfo setObject:NAME_TITLE_SLOGON forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:PLACEHOLDER_EMPTY];
MPMediaItemArtwork *imageArt =  [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithBoundsSize:image.size requestHandler:^UIImage* _Nonnull(CGSize aSize) { return image; }];

[songInfo setObject:imageArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733040/ios-7-rewind-songs-on-lock-screen-using-avplayer might be useful.

Comment: @matt It's not the same, because my slider works perfectly. I also use - - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent but no one positive result...=\

Comment: And also my infocenter works correctly because  i have name song on lockscreen

Comment: You say your slider works perfectly but clearly that's not the case as it is disabling the rest of the interface. I am not an expert but it seems to me that the suggestions about updating the command center's info about playback rate and playback position might be quite germane here.

Comment: @matt my slider works perfectly because i can change playback rate of my player. All controls has been disabled when MPRemoteCommandCenter called...

Comment: Well you are not showing enough of your code for me to comment further. You must have lots more relevant MPRemoteCommandCenter code (what happens when user taps play / pause, etc.); please show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192803/discussion-between-genevios-and-matt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the play / pause button as an example. It is not enough to *enable* it. You also have to *implement* it (I apologize for writing in Swift; I am too lazy to translate back into Objective-C, but you can surely see the point):

```
let mprc = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
mprc.playCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(doPlay))
mprc.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(doPause))
```

and so forth, along with actual `doPlay` and `doPause` implementations.

Comment: MPRemoteCommand *playCommand = [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter]playCommand];
        [playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playSelector:)];
        
           [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand setEnabled:YES];

Comment: It's also no one result..Exactly, when i push on my interface player - Pause, button pause/play - active! but when player start to be play - lockscreen button disabled again...

Comment: [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playCommand)]; This is solve my problem! Thanks @matt

Comment: You are right. I implement play and stop command, it shows disabled button. I follow your suggestion, it shows enable button when I implement the pause function.